# Empty or strange cost path output in ArcGIS 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, cost-path

I´m trying to map green corridors between different stands of hardwood, using Spatial Analyst Cost path tool. I think my cost distance and backlink raster are OK, but the cost path output normally gives a default message, saying in the Results that its empty. 
In the map view, all that exists are a few raster cells, on and around the input feature/raster data, sometimes in a gradient from green (good, low costs) in the north and red (high costs) in the south.
Attached some pictures (upper: cost distance, middle: backlink, lower (cost path) to show what it looks like. This specific cost path result was however different, but still useless.

Anyone got solution for this?

[image]

Comment: Are they all in the same coordinate system? Sometimes that can cause empty results?

Comment: @jbchurchill I´m afraid they are, so no luck there.

Answer (score 1):

Make all input (cost, dir rasters) the exact same extent, pixel size, snap raster.
Use environment to make output from CostPath exactly the same same extent, pixel size, snap raster.  The CostPath, CostDistance geoprocessing tools work much better with consistent extent/cell size/snap raster and all inputs should be rasters (not features for any of the processing)